# Reference Object Property with JSON.Net when property has special characters

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

I am using JSON.Net to update an object within an XML File. This works great! However, I need to update a property that has some special charecters in it and I can't find any information out there on how to do this with JSON.Net.

**XML**

```
<ProfileSettings>{
  "Name": "Default",
  "Status": "New",
  "DeploymentVariants": {
    "SPSite": {
      "Signature": "SPSite",
      "Type": "SPSite",
      "Label": "SharePoint Site",
      "Source": "Solution",
      "DefaultValue": "http://google.com",
      "Value": "http://google.com"
    },
    "Process/Participant[@Name=\"Manager\"]&gt;User": {
      "Signature": "Process/Participant[@Name=\"Manager\"]&gt;User",
      "Type": "SPUser",
      "Label": "User for swim lane Manager",
      "Source": "Swimlane",
      "DefaultValue": "John Smith",
      "Value": "John Smith"
    }
  },
  "DeploymentScripts": {},
  "SPList": "mySPList"
}</DeploymentProfile>
```

In order to update the DefaultValue in the SPSite Object, I can use JSON.Net like so:

```
dynamic fromSolution = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(profileObject);
fromSolution.DeploymentVariants.SPSite.DefaultValue = txtSPSite.Text;
```

However, this won't be true if I'm trying to access the Process/Participant[@Name=\"Manager\"]>User object. How can I access a property when it's got special characters like this one?

`fromSolution.DeploymentVariants.Process.DefaultValue` did not work and obviously including special charecters within that will just result in runtime errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>`. You can use dictionary syntax:

```
fromSolution.DeploymentVariants["Process/Participant[@Name=\"Manager\"]>User"].DefaultValue
```

Comment: Thanks Athari, this works! However, is there a better way of doing it as `@Name=\"Manager\" can be called something else...

Comment: @mwilson Enumerate `JObject`'s properties then. Looks for properties and methods named `Property` or something like that (I don't remember exact name). I would question design of your configuration though. You're probaby doing something wrong if you have to do this.

Comment: Yea, not my design. Have to work with what I'm given. Thanks for helping!!